# Building a Javascript Array (JSON format) dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I need to generate an array of JSON. Example below:

```
[
    {
        "DataCategoryGroupId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
        "AnswerOptionIds": [
            "76e32546-0e26-4037-b253-823b21f6eefb",
            "10d02a3e-9f9f-49fd-8806-e0b180465b7d"
        ]
    },
    {
        "DataCategoryGroupId": "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333",
        "AnswerOptionIds": [
            "ee795c1b-71d1-476a-84f7-0d8084e25617",
            "b611309e-ccfc-44c4-a0e1-60f0767d20ba",
            "7066eb9a-6d08-4f34-8348-b10523e8a568"
        ]
    }
]
```

I try to build it in the following way:

```
var postParams = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < dataCategories.length; i++) {
                var postElement = {
                    DataCategoryGroupId: dataCategories[i].DataCategoryId,
                    AnswerOptionIds: dataCategories[i].AnswerOptionIds
                };
                postParams.push(postElement);
            }
```

As an example of what is inside dataCategories, consider the following debug code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataCategories.length; i++) {
                console.log("Data Category Id: " + dataCategories[i].DataCategoryId);
                console.log("Answer Option Ids: " + dataCategories[i].AnswerOptionIds);
            }
```

The output of the following bit of code is:

```
Data Category Id: 22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222
Answer Option Ids: bf835029-5e3b-40d5-8736-34fe5121c5f4,10d02a3e-9f9f-49fd-8806-e0b180465b7d
Data Category Id: 33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333
Answer Option Ids: ee795c1b-71d1-476a-84f7-0d8084e25617,b611309e-ccfc-44c4-a0e1-60f0767d20ba,0049e914-520d-4721-92d2-9b0a050d7381
```

So, the data is there, but the method I have for constructing the JSON is incorrect as the models are not matched by the controller. If I use a rest client with the example JSON that I provided above, the models match.

Could someone please point out the error I am making in constructing my JSON.

Comment: are you looking for [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ?

Comment: I don't understand your debug code (I mean I don't understand why you are doing it in this way). What does `JSON.stringify(postParams)` return?

Comment: What is the exact problem? What JSON is it producing? Where are you generating the JSON? What you have shown looks fine.

Comment: @laszlokiss88 Did not know about JSON.stringify(postParams). Looks like the JSON generated is correct. The error is somewhere else (on why the models don't match).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you need a deep copy. Right now you're copying a reference to the input array. If that changes, your post data will change.

```
var postParams = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dataCategories.length; i++) {
    dataElement = dataCategories[i];

    var postElement = {
        DataCategoryGroupId: dataElement.DataCategoryId,
        AnswerOptionIds: []
    };

    for (var j = 0; j < dataElement.AnswerOptionIds.length; j++){
        postElement.AnswerOptionIds.push(dataElement.AnswerOptionIds[j];
    }
    postParams.push(postElement);
}
```